# Country Selector (AJAX/JSON + PHP)

Tags: php, json, ajax, country

Could you please help me with this situation?

Let's say I have this right now:

**HTML**

```html
<select name="insta_country_code" class="widget-user-country country-selector" data-account-name="
    <?php echo $account1['Username'] ?>">
    <option value="br">Brazil</option>
    <option value="cl">Chile</option>
    <option value="es" selected>Spain</option>
    <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
    <option value="gb">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="cr">Costa Rica</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.country-selector').change(function () {
        var ig_name = $(this).data('account-name');
        var country_code = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'change-country.php',
            data: {
                insta_user: ig_name,
                country_code: country_code,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data['status'] != 1) {
                    $.alert('server error');
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $.alert('error');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

What should be my `.php` file? I need to do something like this:

```php
$InstagramCountry = $data['country_code'];
$InstagramUsername = $data['insta_user']);

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE igaccounts SET Country='$InstagramCountry' WHERE Username='$InstagramUsername'");
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_*`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone What should I use? Are you making reference to MySQLi? I appreciate any information. Thanks!

Comment: Kevin RE: `mysql_` please read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

As you're using `POST` method to send data to your server side php code, you can catch the data using `$_POST` OR `$_REQUEST` global variable like this-

```
$InstagramCountry = $_POST['country_code'];
$InstagramUsername = $_POST['insta_user']);
```

You said vai comment that you're getting error on ajax call, you can try this way to debug what is the reason of that error using-

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
  }
```

To capture mysqli error, (I urge you to use **mysqli** and avoid to use the old/deprecated **mysql**), SEE [MORE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

```
$result = mysql_query('UPDATE igaccounts SET Country='$InstagramCountry' WHERE Username='$InstagramUsername');

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about $_POST too but my problem is converting the entire PHP file according to my current JS.

Comment: is that hepled i.e is there anything you're still having problem?

Comment: No matter what I use on my PHP file the system is giving me the $.alert('error');, I think I need to clarify that all inside the .php with results, success (or not), but I never used AJAX/JSON

Comment: I appreciate your help. It's weird because now with that debug option I'm not receiving errors when I try to choose a different country option, but it doesn't execute and update MySQL query.

Comment: I'm in the same situation :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should must work for your case. I have tested it in my localhost.
For your HTML File:

```
<select name="insta_country_code" class="widget-user-country country-selector" data-account-name="<?php echo $account1['Username'] ?>">
            <option value="br">Brazil</option>
            <option value="cl">Chile</option>
            <option value="es" selected>Spain</option>
            <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
            <option value="gb">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="cr">Costa Rica</option>
        </select>
```

For your JS File:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.country-selector').change(function () {
                    var ig_name = $(this).data('account-name');
                    var country_code = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'change-country.php',
                        data: {
                            insta_user: ig_name,
                            country_code: country_code,
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data['status'] != 1) {
                                $.alert('server error');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            $.alert('error');
                        }
                    });
                })
            });
        </script>
```

For your .PHP File:

```
<?php 
$data = $_REQUEST; 
$InstagramCountry = $data['country_code'];
$InstagramUsername = $data['insta_user'];
echo "insta_user=".$InstagramUsername . " AND country_code=" . $InstagramCountry; exit;
```

Tell me if still need any help bro.

Comment: No matter what I use on my PHP file the system is giving me the $.alert('error');, I think I need to clarify that all inside the .php with results, success (or not), but I never used AJAX/JSON

Comment: And what I need to do is this in .php: mysql_query("UPDATE igaccounts SET Country='$InstagramCountry' WHERE Username='$InstagramUsername'")

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it this way:

your php script:

```
                  if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
                          $action = $_POST["action"];
                          switch ($action) {
                              case 'SLC':
                                  if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
                                      $id = $_POST["id"];
                                      if (is_int($id)) {
                                          $query = "select * from alumni_users where userId = '$id' ";
                                          $update = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
                                          $response = array();
                                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($update)){
                                          .......
                                          fill your response here

                                          }
                                         echo json_encode($response);
                                      }
                                  }
                                  break;

                          }
                      }
```

Where action is a command you want to do SLC, UPD, DEL etc and id is a parameter

then in your ajax:

```
                function getdetails() {
                      var value = $('#userId').val(); // value can be your array ! note: if you send a object json_encode(json_decode(,MyObj,true))
                     return $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "getInfo.php",
                          data: {action: "SLC",id: value }
                      })
                  }
```

call it like this:

```
    getdetails().done(function(response){
                  var data=JSON.parse(response);
                  if (data != null) {
                  //do somthing with your Data
                  }
                  })
```

Hope it Helps